# IIS cannot handle jqgrid request

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis, jqgrid

I have a little problem with IIS. I am developing C# MVC application which uses jqgrid. One of my grids with id @academies_griddata is populated with data specific to chosen academy (Id is then determined). At the beginning no academy is chosen so i set the parameters of jqgrid as follows:

```
`...$("#contracts_griddata").jqGrid({
  mtype: 'GET',
  datatype: 'local',
  colNames: [...`
```

After academy is chosen in jquery code I set paramters as follows:

```
var Id = $("#Id").val();
  $("#contracts_griddata").jqGrid('setGridParam',
    { url: "/Academies/ContractGridData?AcademyId=" + Id, datatype: "json" });
  $("#contracts_griddata").trigger('reloadGrid');
```

When I run the code in Visual Studio it works like a dream, but after publishing to IIS I get error:

> 404 Not Found

When I check a request in Firebug it is exactly the same e.g.:

```
http://localhost/Academies/ContractGridData?AcademyId=551&_search=false&nd=1383686029082&rows=5&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc
```

Anyone can help please?

Comment: this is unlikely to have anything to do with iis other than the fact that iis is your webserver. It looks like your path might be wrong. Did you publish it into a subfolder of the webroot rather than the webroot?

Comment: YES - exactly. It was all about paths. Oh God - too much work. Thanks a lot.